# Azure: access RoleEnvironment from a website

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a cloud service project
with web role (asp.net) and worker roles.

in my **Default.aspx.cs** file i tried to access the worker role:

```
var role = RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyWorkerRole"];
```

but i got **"role discovery data is unavailable"** exception.

is there a way to accsess it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug this locally or running from Azure?

If locally, try to switch to Visual Studio webserver.  If you are running on VS webserver, try  iis express instead.

HTH

Comment: where can i switch it?

Comment: Project properties in Visual Studio, Web tab.